# Linear transformation of random vector has bounded moments?

Tags: pr.probability, moments

Suppose that the random $p$-vector $\mathbf{y}=(Y_1, Y_2,\ldots, Y_p)'$
with $p\to\infty$ satisfies:

- $\mathrm{E}Y_i = 0$, $\mathrm{E}Y_i^2=1$ for any $1\leqslant i \leqslant p$;
- $\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$
- for any $m\geqslant 1$ and $1\leqslant i \leqslant p$, $\sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1} \mathrm{E}Y_{i}^m < \infty$.

The $p\times p$ matrix $\mathbf{A}_p$ has bounded spectral norm, that is, $\sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1}\|\mathbf{A}_p\|_2 = \sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1}\left(\max\limits_{|\mathbf{x}|_2\neq 0}\frac{|\mathbf{A}_p\mathbf{x}|_2}{|\mathbf{x}|_2}\right)<\infty$.
Denote $\widetilde{\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf{A}_p\mathbf{y}=(\widetilde{Y}_1, \widetilde{Y}_2, \dots, \widetilde{Y}_p)$.

**Question**: Does $\sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1}\mathrm{E}\widetilde{Y}_i^m<\infty$ for any $m\geqslant 1$ and any $1\leqslant i \leqslant p$?

It is obvious that the expectation $\mathrm{E}(\widetilde{\mathbf{y}})=\boldsymbol{0}$, but I do not know how to deal with higher-order moments.

Comment: @MattF. Thanks for your comments. $Y_i$'s have the same distribution but they are not independent (only uncorrelated). I change the notation $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{A}_p$.